# $p$ odd prime and $n$ integer. Prove that $x^n - p$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

By Eisenstein's criterion I know that the polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, since $p$ divides $p$ and $p^2$ does not divide $p$. But I do not know how to extend to $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: You need to know a bit more about the primes of $\Bbb{Z}[i]$. For example $5$ is not a prime in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ because it factors $5=(2+i)(2-i)$. However, $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ has all the properties you need to apply Eisenstein such as ____, and those factors of $5$ are ____.